# Fetching data from database is taking a lot of time for 600k records in python using cx_oracle library

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

While fetching the data from Database using cx_*oracle library and pandas pd.read_*sql in python it's taking an hour to fetch almost 600 000 records into a dataframe.

I have at least 6 queries to run with same case. tried chunking the data but it didn't work.

I tried chunking the data and tried an optimised query as well still it's taking the same time. since fetching and loading in dataframe is taking time.

Comment: Please use universal measurements, and avoid using local words like *lakh* that are not understood by everyone

Comment: What have you done to establish *where* your bottleneck is? Why do you suspect the database? If your application code is processing the data row by row, I would start there - that would explain why query optimization didn't make any difference.

Comment: Share some code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

The latest release of cx_Oracle (which got renamed to python-oracledb) runs in a 'Thin' mode by default which bypasses the Oracle Client libraries. This means that in many cases it is faster for data loads. Please try python-oracledb. Using [python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in thin mode should help you with performance.

Installation steps are simple, Install with something like `python -m pip install oracledb`. Please see the [upgrading documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html#upgrading-from-cx-oracle-8-3-to-python-oracledb). Best Practices to follow on [python-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/tree/main/samples).

The tuning suggested in the above response applies to python-oracledb as well.

Here, I have compared the time taken to fetch 600k rows:

1. by pandas's read_sql() and
2. python-oracledb's fetchall().

> Note:  I am not sure about the data row size and types you are trying to fetch, So I have used a simple data set with two columns and 600k rows. I have used [Tuning python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-python-oracledb) and modified the cursor.arraysize parameter which has significantly improved the performance in fetching the rows.

> Consideration: python-oracledb's fetchall() returns the data as a list of tuples, I have considered the conversion time from a list to pandas Dataframe locally.

| cursor.arraysize | pandas's read_sql() | python-oracledb fetchall() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3764 seconds | 1846 seconds |
| 1000 | 3690 seconds | 185 seconds |
| 10000 | 3695 seconds | 23 seconds |
| 100000 | 3712 seconds | 22 seconds |

Adjusting cursor.arraysize according to your row size improves the performance

This is the script I used to fetch the rows using python-oracledb fetchall() and converting it to pandas Dataframe.

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sql
import oracledb as oracledb

# Database Credentials
username = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")

cp = oracledb.ConnectParams()
cp.parse_connect_string(os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING"))

eng = sql.create_engine(f'oracle+oracledb://{username}:{password}@{cp.host}:{cp.port}/?service_name={cp.service_name}')
tablename = input("enter table name: ")
cursorsize = input("enter cursor size: ")
sqlStatement = 'select * from {}'.format(tablename)
conn = eng.pool._creator()
start = time.time()
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.arraysize = int(cursorsize)
    cursor.execute(sqlStatement)
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    #loading the result list in pandas Dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns = ['description','done'])
    elapsed = (time.time() - start)
    print("Prefetchrows:", cursor.prefetchrows, "Arraysize:", cursor.arraysize)
    print("Retrieved", len(res), "rows in", elapsed, "seconds")
```

Please follow these best practices to fetch the large data rows from Oracle Database.

> Python packages used versions:
>
> - python-oracledb - 1.3.1
> - pandas - 1.5.3
> - SQLAlchemy - 2.0.5