# How can I connect to MSSQL and Oracle databases in Python with DSN and read tables into Pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I want to connect with one python program to different databases (MSSQL and Oracle for now but maybe also postgres/mysql later) and ideally read queries/tables into pandas dataframes. For compatability reasons on some other packages im using python 3.7. The connections to the databases are only available through DSN (read/configurable from a file but thats a non-issue).

The problem is that sqlalchemy (1.4) does not support a connection to an oracle database using a DSN (unless i just didnt find any answer to it on the internet), so I tried connecting with cx_oracle directly (which worked fine), but then i cant use pandas.read_sql_table(), so I would prefer it if there was another solution to somehow still get a sqlalchemy connection to the Oracle DB using a DSN. For MSSQL the sqlalchemy connection works fine using pyodbc as dialect.
Some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sqla

loginuser = 'username'
loginpwd = 'password'
logindsn = 'dsnname'
dbtype = 'oracle'/'MSSQL' #this is read from a file along with the other variables, just put it here directly to not make the code overly complicated

if dbtype == 'oracle':
    conn = ora.connect(user=loginuser, password=loginpwd, dsn=logindsn) #using a dsn doesnt work with sqlalchemy afaik
elif dbtype == 'MSSQL':
    engine = sqla.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+loginuser+':'+loginpwd+'@'+logindsn)
    conn = engine.connect()

testdf = pd.read_sql_table('Employees', conn) # for MSSQL this works, for oracle it gives an error that pd.read_sql_table (which id like to use) can only be used with a sqlalchemy-connection
```

I'm willing to swap to a different library that allows me to connect to both Oracle and MSSQL easily if there's a better solution than pandas+sqlalchemy...

Comment: If the fancy automated tools don't fit your scenario, then you have to do it by hand.  It isn't hard.  Once you have a connection, the query format is the same, and you can use `fetchall` to fill in the dataframe.

Comment: @TimRoberts well it would also make other cases easier, such as having always the same query instead of having different paramizations "(?)" and ":" to prevent sql injection... but yeah i guess if theres no easy solution ill have to go the long road

Comment: @Erbs PEP-249 specifies `module.paramstyle` attribute that denotes parametrization type used by engine. You may use this information when building the query.

Comment: @astentx can you show me an example how i would use that? im quite new to working with (multiple) databases with python so i dont quite understand, if that makes me able to write queries as a single query or if it just saves me looking up the actual syntax and i still need to write 2 (or more) queries/replace chars in the string depending on db used

Comment: It's only a little bit awkward.  `rep = ora.paramstyle`, then queries are like `sql = f"SELECT name FROM users WHERE id={rep};"` instead of just assuming `?` or `%s`.

Comment: For connection syntaxes with the latest cx_Oracle release (now called python-oracledb), see https://medium.com/gitconnected/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19 and 
https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c

Comment: @ChristopherJones that still doesnt let me connect via dsn but okay...

Comment: The `connect_args={...}` syntax shown in the python-oracledb examples in those links lets you pass a dsn of any form, including if you define 'dsn' to mean also containing credentials.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a direct connection with Oracle Database using
  [python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
- Fetch the data rows using python-oracledb's
  [fetch](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#fetch-methods)
  methods.
- This data is returned in a list of rows. Convert the list into pandas DataFrame locally, Please refer to a sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76205982/fetching-data-from-database-is-taking-a-lot-of-time-for-600k-records-in-python-u/76472635#76472635).

> Note: [Python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) is the new name for the latest release of Oracle's popular cx_Oracle driver runs in a 'Thin' mode by default which bypasses the Oracle Client libraries.

Comment: i ditched the pandas dataframe idea by now and am just using sqlalchemy and oop classes and connect directly to the database without odbc, cause it just makes it easier to swap between different databases as i can use the sqlalchemy orm

Answer (score 0):

> I tried connecting with cx_oracle directly (which worked fine), but then i cant use pandas.read_sql_table()

For the record, with SQLAlchemy 1.4 and pandas 1.5.3, `.read_sql_table()` works fine for `oracle+cx_oracle://`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(
    "oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/?service_name=xepdb1"
)

df = pd.read_sql_table("table1", engine)
print(df)
"""
   id  txt
0   1  foo
"""
```

Comment: "For the record", read my question again, its not a service, its a dsn

Answer (score 0):

From SQLAlchemy 1.4 docs:

> Connections with tnsnames.ora or Oracle Cloud Alternatively, if no
> port, database name, or service_name is provided, the dialect will use
> an Oracle DSN “connection string”. This takes the “hostname” portion
> of the URL as the data source name. For example, if the tnsnames.ora
> file contains a Net Service Name of myalias as below:

```
myalias =   
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mymachine.example.com)(PORT = 1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVER = DEDICATED)
       (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb1)
     )
  )
```

> The cx_Oracle dialect connects to this database service when myalias is the hostname portion of the URL, without specifying a port,
> database name or service_name:

```
create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@myalias/?encoding=UTF-8&nencoding=UTF-8")
```

I also noticed in the question above that there is no `create_engine` section for the Oracle connection, which is required whether you use a DSN or otherwise when using `SQLAlchemy`.

Now I will admit that I'm not an Oracle expert in any form or fashion here, but some information about setting the Oracle TNS (if not already set) and using the DSN correctly can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97338_01/doc/webdb.22/a77053/chapter6.htm) from Oracle Docs.

Follow up question, if you're willing to explore other python packages, why not upgrade to `SQLAlchemy 2.0`? Same syntax still apply for the most part, and additional features and performance improvements have been added.

You can read more [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html)